# Why is this template parameter not deducible?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, c++14, template-meta-programming

Edit: I made a simple mistake in using SFINAE. Fixing that resolves the compiler error I mention below. However I'm still curious about *why* the template parameter can't be deduced in this case.

I wanted to write a C++14 template metaprogram to calculate the greatest common divisor (GCD) of a `std::integer_sequence`. After some tinkering I came up with this *almost* complete example:

```
template <typename T, T A, T B, T... Ints>
struct GCD<std::integer_sequence<T, A, B, Ints...>> : 
       GCD<typename std::integer_sequence<T, GCD_pair<T, A, B>::value, Ints...>> {};

template <class T, T A, T B>
struct GCD<std::integer_sequence<T, A, B>> : 
       GCD_pair<T, A, B> {};

int main() {      
  using seq = std::integer_sequence<int, 65537, 5, 10>;
  cout << GCD<seq>::value << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I just peel off the first two elements of the integer sequence, and find the GCD of them using the to-be-written `GCD_pair` metafunction. Then I apply `GCD` to the result of `GCD_pair` and the remaining elements.

The "obvious" implementation of `GCD_pair` does not compile:

```
// This does not work:
// type 'T' of template argument '0' depends on a template parameter
template <typename T, T M, T N>
struct GCD_pair : std::integral_constant<T, GCD_pair<T, N, M % N>::value> {};

template <typename T, T M>
struct GCD_pair<T, M, 0> : std::integral_constant<T, M> {};
```

So I tried another possible implementation using SFINAE:

```
// This doesn't work either:
// template parameters not deducible in partial specialization
template <typename T, T M, T N, typename = void>
struct GCD_pair : std::integral_constant<T, M> {};

template <typename T, T M, T N, typename std::enable_if<(M % N != 0)>::type>
struct GCD_pair<T, M, N, void> : std::integral_constant<T, GCD_pair<T, N, M % N>::value> {};
```

Edit: I made an error. See the answer below correcting my use of SFINAE. But I'm still curious about my question:

**Why is the template parameter `typename std::enable_if<(M % N != 0)>::type` not deducible?** Is it not deducible *ever* in principle, or could parameters such as in this case *actually* be deduced in practice? In other words, could this be considered a compiler implementation oversight?

For what it's worth, I was able to implement [a slightly different version](http://cpp.sh/7ekr7) by essentially "hiding" the conditional (`M % N != 0`) in a `bool` template parameter. However, **I think both of the above are reasonable implementations** because `operator%` and comparison to `0` with `operator!=` are perfectly well-defined for all of C++'s integral types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
template <typename T, T M, T N>
struct GCD_pair<T, M, N, typename std::enable_if<(M % N != 0)>::type>
    : std::integral_constant<T, GCD_pair<T, N, M % N>::value> {};
```

Because you are using C++14, you can also simplify it by using `std::enable_if_t`:

```
template <typename T, T M, T N>
struct GCD_pair<T, M, N, std::enable_if_t<(M % N != 0)>>
    : std::integral_constant<T, GCD_pair<T, N, M % N>::value> {};
```

In both cases, if the condition `(M % N != 0)` applies, both the primary template and the specialization are valid once instantiated, but the specialization is, well, more specialized and thus it is chosen.
On the other side, if the condition doesn't apply, the specialization is silently discarded because of sfinae rules, but the primary template is still valid and thus chosen.

Note also that `type` in `typename std::enable_if<(M % N != 0)>::type` is `void` when the condition is true.
Because of that, you template parameters list would be theoretically:

```
template <typename T, T M, T N, void>
struct GCD_pair<T, M, N, void>: std::integral_constant<T, GCD_pair<T, N, M % N>::value> {};
```

However, `void` is not allowed as a non-type template parameter.

Finally, from the standard we have that:

> A partial specialization matches a given actual template argument list if the template arguments of the partial specialization can be deduced from the actual template argument list

Also:

> If the template arguments of a partial specialization cannot be deduced because of the structure of its template-parameter-list and the template-id, the program is ill-formed.

In your case, the fourth parameter of the specialization cannot be deduced for obvious reasons. Even if it was valid (and it is not, because it results in `void` as mentioned), what you get is a type or a non-type parameter for which you don't have an actual type or value.
Suppose you have the following specialization:

```
template <typename T, T M, T N, int>
struct GCD_pair<T, M, N, void> : std::integral_constant<T, GCD_pair<T, N, M % N>::value> {};
```

How could the compiler deduce the value for the last template parameter?
It cannot and that's more or less your case.
Probably it should rather detect the fact that the parameter list is ill-formed if the condition to `std::enable_if` is valid, anyway both are errors and you are getting one of them out of the compilation phase.

What you would benefit from is something like this:

```
template <typename T, T M, T N, typename = std::enable_if_t<(M % N != 0)>>
struct GCD_pair<T, M, N, void> : std::integral_constant<T, GCD_pair<T, N, M % N>::value> {};
```

Or this:

```
template <typename T, T M, T N, std::enable_if_t<(M % N != 0)>* = nullptr>
struct GCD_pair<T, M, N, void> : std::integral_constant<T, GCD_pair<T, N, M % N>::value> {};
```

Anyway, both of them are invalid for default arguments are not allowed in partial specializations.

Comment: And additionally `GCD` needs a primary template, e.g. `template <typename> struct GCD;`.

Comment: Sure enough! Silly me, I made a simple mistake.

Comment: So I quickly accepted this because you pointed out my error in using SFINAE -- however I reconsidered because my question still stands. Why can't the template parameter be deduced?

Comment: @JohnDuck Added more details. Let me know if it's fine for you.

Comment: @JohnDuck You're welcome. I hope the answer is fine now.